# LOAD, UNLOAD lines meaning in journal: /var/log/auth.log

Tags: linux, debian, linux-audit

I have many following lines in my journal file: /var/log/auth.log:

```
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=18 op=UNLOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=17 op=UNLOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=16 op=UNLOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=15 op=UNLOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=12 op=UNLOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=11 op=UNLOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=19 op=LOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=20 op=LOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=21 op=LOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=22 op=LOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=23 op=LOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=24 op=LOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=24 op=UNLOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=23 op=UNLOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=22 op=UNLOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=21 op=UNLOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=20 op=UNLOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=19 op=UNLOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=25 op=LOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=26 op=LOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=27 op=LOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=28 op=LOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=29 op=LOAD
      Mar  4 09:34:39 hostname audit: AUDIT1334 prog-id=30 op=LOAD
```

Can you explain me, what this lines means?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have something configured that emits messages from the audit subsystem to syslog/journal in a very rudimentary form.

Perhaps you would find more detailed messages in logs stored in `/var/log/audit/`?

Anyway, `AUDIT1334` suggests that whatever converted the audit subsystem message to syslog form might not have known how to fully parse audit subsystem message type #1334.

According to the [audit message dictionary](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-documentation/blob/main/specs/messages/message-dictionary.csv) in the programming documentation of the Linux audit subsystem, message #1334 is `AUDIT_BPF`, indicating loading or unloading of a [Berkeley Packet Filter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/bpf/index.html) program.

(Berkeley Packet Filter, or BPF for short, is a Linux kernel subsystem that allows user-space programs to specify event-driven bytecode programs that would execute in kernel mode. A program could use it to tell the kernel to pre-filter its network traffic, or to implement network load balancing schemes, but the current implementation of BPF includes a lot more than just network-related functionality. [You can find a more technical introduction of BPF here.](https://docs.cilium.io/en/latest/bpf/) Apparently [BPF has also some potential to be used offensively](https://embracethered.com/blog/posts/2021/offensive-bpf-bpftrace/).)

The `AUDIT_BPF` audit event type [seems to have been added to the kernel in late 2019](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-audit/patch/20191205102552.19407-1-jolsa@kernel.org/), so whatever is processing your audit messages is probably from 2019 or older, and your kernel seems to be newer than that.

Apparently the use of cgroups by `systemd` can involve a number of small BPF programs. So if your system uses `systemd` and you were rebooting or otherwise restarting a large number of systemd service units at the time those messages were generated, the messages might be normal... but I'd still consider updating the component that is creating those log messages (perhaps the syslog plugin for `auditd`?) to get those messages in a more informative form.

Otherwise, seeing so many processes (different `prog-id` values) quickly loading and unloading BPF programs with no good reason would make me a bit suspicious. The fact that your audit message handling process apparently does not know what audit message type #1334 is suggests to me your system might not be entirely up to date and so might be vulnerable to known attacks.